# Select an SVG element by a particular attribute value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, svg

I have a small function where i'm required to find the radius and centre of a circle which was added dynamically.

```
function CalculateEdgeData(nodeId1,nodeId2)
        {
          console.log(nodeId1);
          var node1cx =  $( "circle[nodeId="+nodeId1+"]" ).attr('cx');
          console.log(node1cx);
        }
```

But `$( "circle[nodeId="+nodeId1+"]" )` is returning null. Is it possible to select an svg element this way using jquery ?

the dom structure is as follows(dynamically added through d3js , but rendered like this in browser).

`<circle cx="150" cy="100" r="40" nodeId="1" class="head" style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></circle>`

when i tried in console `$(circle)` was returning array of all circles , and also `nodeId1` has the required value too. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Can include `svg`  , `html` at Question ? , create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: Try to surround your id variable by single quotes, like so `$( "circle[nodeId='"+nodeId1+"']" )`, and let us know.

Comment: There is no issue with code syntax but can you check if your function is fired or registered before dom element is populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing quotes around `value` at `[name='value']` selector

```js
function CalculateEdgeData(nodeId1, nodeId2) {
  console.log(nodeId1);
  // added single quotes `'` before, after double quotes at `'" + nodeId1 + "'`
  var node1cx = $("circle[nodeId='" + nodeId1 + "']").attr('cx');
  console.log(node1cx);
}

CalculateEdgeData("1")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="40" nodeId="1" class="head" style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(204, 204, 204);" />
  <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" />
</svg>
```

Comment: i don't think it matters even this works `$("circle[nodeId=" + nodeId1 + "]").attr('cx')`

Comment: @RaunakKathuria  _"i don't think it matters even this works $("circle[nodeId=" + nodeId1 + "]").attr('cx')"_ Without single quotes `console.log(node1cx);` returns `undefined` https://jsfiddle.net/houbp50z/

Comment: @RaunakKathuria _"works for me, tried on firefox console "_ What is returned at `console` at https://jsfiddle.net/houbp50z/ ?

Comment: even this https://jsfiddle.net/houbp50z/1/ returns undefined, i tried with numeric 1 not string earlier

Comment: @RaunakKathuria _"even this jsfiddle.net/houbp50z/1 returns undefined, i tried with numeric 1 not string"_ At chromium, without single quotes `console.log(node1cx);` returns `undefined` ; with single quotes, `150` is returned see also stacksnippets